# Writing a program to determine a palindrome. I have to use toUppercase and toLowercase to make it case insensitive

Tags: java, netbeans

I feel like I'm only missing a few steps. I'm not looking for someone to finish it.. just need help in the right direction.

The problem with it is it still says that for example, "Noon" isn't a palindrome.

I'm not sure how to convert it any further.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a string of 8 or less characters: ");
    String s = input.nextLine();

    int low = 0;

    int high = s.length() - 1 ;

    boolean isPalindrome = true;

    while(low < high){
        if(s.charAt(low) !=s.charAt(high))
        {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    low++;
    high--;
} 

    String upper = s.toUpperCase(); 
    String lower = s.toLowerCase();  

    if(high>8)
    {
        System.out.println("Too Long!");
    }
    else if(isPalindrome)
    {
        System.out.println(s + " is a Palindrome");
    }
    else if((isPalindrome)&&s.toUpperCase().equals(s.toUpperCase()))
    {
        System.out.println(s + " is a Palindrome");
    }
    else
        System.out.println(s + " is not a Palindrome");
```

Comment: Help how? -- You've not posted a specific question yet. To help improve your question above please have a look at [Jon Skeet's StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). It's an abbreviated version of his wonderful longer post on [Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: The art of programming is taking the task and breaking it down into specific steps.  That is where only practice (in the form of this homework) will help you, as from there, writing the code is the easy part.

Comment: hint - by the time you get to the s.toUpperCase in the else if section, isPalindrome is already false.  You need to do the uppercasing at the point you're checking each char.

Answer (score 0):

change the logic to check the characters like below n try.
it will make it case insensitive.

```
 while(low < high){
            if(s.toUpperCase().charAt(low) != s.toUpperCase().charAt(high))
            {
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }
        low++;
        high--;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package javaprograme;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromStringExample {
    public static boolean palidrom(String name)
    {
        char[] ch = name.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0,j=ch.length-1; i<(ch.length/2); i++,j--)
        {
            if(ch[i]!=ch[j])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = input.nextLine();
        if(s.length()>8)
        {
            System.out.println("Too Long!");
        }
        else 
        {       
            boolean value =palidrom(s);
            s.toUpperCase();
            if(!value)
            {
                System.out.println("Given String is not a palindrom");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Given String is a palindrom");
            }
        }
    }
}
```